# Can i prevent jvm from checking compile time error?

Tags: java

I don't import ArrayList. Is it possible to generate .class file from the bellow code.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String []args) {
      Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList");
      ArrayList list;
  }
```

}

Comment: You explicitly wrote that you need the class: `ArrayList list;`. And you do nothing with the call to `Class.forname(...)`

Answer (score 0):

There are checked and unchecked exceptions in java. Since the method you are calling **`throws ClassNotFoundException`** you must handle that by either catching it or declaring it in your method signature.

And as the name suggests a **checked** exception will be checked and you can't have the compiler ignore it.

If you are trying to avoid using a try catch you can declare that the method `throws` a certain exception, in your case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException { 
    // your code here ... 
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But it doesn't throw any exception. It is an error says... cannot find symbol
                ArrayList list;
                ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class Test